# How to configure specific upstream push refspec for Git when used with Gerrit?

Tags: git, push, gerrit, refspec

I'm setting up Git with [Gerrit Code Review](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) and am looking for a way to make the necessary Git commands relatively straightforward for users who might be new to Git.

The commands I currently have for starting a new feature branch are essentially (assuming Gerrit is `origin`):

```
git checkout baseline
git pull
git checkout -b work1234
git push -u origin work1234
```

This starts a new work package `work1234` branched from some `baseline`, and the final push creates the branch in Gerrit and sets the upstream. So `.git/config` looks something like:

```
[branch "work1234"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/work1234
```

Now, Gerrit wants new commits for review to be pushed to a special refspec, `refs/for/work1234` for example. I can do this manually with:

```
git push origin work1234:refs/for/work1234
```

What I would like to do is find some way to set up `.git/config` so that a plain `git push` will push the current branch to the refspec on the remote that Gerrit requires. I have looked at the following `git config` areas:

- `branch.<name>.*` - doesn't seem to have any specific option for setting the push refspec
- `push.default` - I sort of want `upstream` here
- `remote.<name>.push` - I tried `refs/heads/*:refs/for/*` here but `git push` always wants to push *all* local branches in this case, while I just want the *current* branch

If I can't make Git do this by itself, I'll write a small wrapper script that fully specifies the refspecs. However, it would be better if Git could push to the right place natively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up writing a new `git-submit` script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    REMOTE=origin
else
    REMOTE=$1
fi

BRANCH=`git symbolic-ref HEAD`
case $BRANCH in
    refs/heads/*)
        BRANCH=`basename $BRANCH`
        ;;
    *)
        echo "I can't figure out which branch you are on."
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

git push $REMOTE HEAD:refs/for/$BRANCH
```

I put this script in `/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-submit` and now there's one command to submit new code to Gerrit for review:

```
$ git submit
```

If Gerrit is not the `origin` remote, then use `git submit <remote>` as appropriate.

Comment: Would there be a simpler git-only solution if I always want to push to a fixed destination, say `refs/for/master`? ([Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664305/equivalent-of-branch-name-merge-for-git-push) my SO question asking that simpler version of your problem.)

Answer (score 4):

Two options I've found:

1) Check out a project I made, ggh: https://github.com/hobbs/ggh

2) You can configure the default push refspec in your remote.  I've only figured out how to do this with a hardcoded remote branch, still trying to figure out how to wildcard the remote refspec so that it always pushes to the remote you're tracking:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = ssh://gerrit/repo
    push =  HEAD:refs/for/master
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an improvement of *Greg Hewgill* answer.

Create a script somewhere on the path, like on your profile bin folder (create one if necessary, even on Windows):

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
$ vi ~/bin/git-submit
```

With the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    REMOTE=origin
else
    REMOTE=$1
fi

BRANCH=`git symbolic-ref HEAD`
case $BRANCH in
    refs/heads/*)
        BRANCH=`basename $BRANCH`
        ;;
    *)
        echo "I can't figure out which branch you are on."
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

REMOTE_BRANCH=`git config --get "branch.$BRANCH.merge"`
if [ -z $REMOTE_BRANCH ]
then
    echo "There is no tracking information for the current branch."
    echo "If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:"
    echo ""
    echo "    git branch --set-upstream $BRANCH <remote>/<branch>"
    echo ""
    exit 1
fi

git push $REMOTE HEAD:refs/for/$REMOTE_BRANCH
```

Supposing you create a remote tracking branch like:

```
$ git checkout -b MyBranch origin/master
```

You can simply call:

```
$ git submit
```

... to push to `refs/for/master` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
git config push.default upstream
git config branch.work1234.merge refs/for/work1234
git config branch.work1234.remote origin
```

or .git/config:

```
[push]
        default = upstream
[branch "work1234"]
        merge = refs/for/work1234
        remote = origin
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to put a wildcard in there anywhere to make it work for all branches.

Comment: This would break the `git-pull` as it'd try to pull from `refs/for/*` which fails. The remote is probably not needed as default is "origin".