# "git push" to Gerrit with a tracking branch

Tags: git, push, gerrit, refspec

Pushing changes to Gerrit requires the rather esoteric command

`git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branchname`

We've scripted this, but I'm looking for a way to do this natively. With git's powerful config, it looks like I can preconfigure most of it[1] so that just `git push` suffices... almost. I'm stuck on the `remote.<name>.push` refspec.

I can already create a *tracking* topic branch so that `git pull` (no other parameters) will pull changes from upstream remote into my topic branch. However with Gerrit, the push and fetch refspecs aren't the same: one fetches (merges) from `refs/heads/trackbranch`, but one pushes to `refs/for/trackbranch`[2]

I can configure a `push` refspec in `remote.<name>.push`, however the syntax is pretty basic: if I put
`push = refs/heads/*:refs/for/*`

Then that will try pushing my `t-foo` topic branch to `refs/for/t-foo`. But git has the information that `t-foo` is tracking `trackbranch`. Can I define a refspec so that git automatically tries to push any `t-foo` to its `refs/for/trackbranch` ?

We're currently using a script to do this, and I suppose I could define a push refspec for each topic branch (possibly through more scripting). I'm hoping there's a native git way of doing this so that we don't need to rely on more custom in-house scripts for our team.

[1] by defining a tracking branch with `git checkout origin/upstream_branch -b topic_branch` or within an existing branch `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/upstream_branch`

[2] pushing to `refs/for/*` creates a changeset for review. With appropriate permissions, one could push to `refs/heads/*` to bypass review, but that negates most of the point of Gerrit.

Comment: "Can I define a refspec so that git automatically tries to push any t-foo to its refs/for/trackbranch?"  No, at least I don't think so today.  What you want to get at is the `fetch=...` mapping machinery git uses with merge names (to map the `remote=` and `merge=` parts) and that doesn't seem to be exposed anywhere.  You could write a program that munches through your set of local branches and computes all this, though (then updates your gitconfig).  Still a bit painful either way.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wish to do. If this is confirmed, why not put it as an answer?

Comment: After more searching, my question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101145/how-to-configure-specific-upstream-push-refspec-for-git-when-used-with-gerrit from two years ago and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320363/push-current-branch-to-gerrit from last year

Answer (score 2):

For some reason :-) I went ahead and tried to write a script to set git config entries, and then found that there seems to be no way to get the desired results directly.

As an alternative, I wrote a script that pushes to the "gerrit review name" (note: I have not actually *used* gerrit so this is essentially untested, though I've run it with the `--dry-run` option and it looks like it Does The Right Thing—but I expect you might want to modify it).  Of course this is probably functionally the same as your own script.

Anyway, you could then have a global or system-wide alias, `git config alias.review` or some such, that runs the script, so that you could say `git review` or `git review branch`.  The alias would just be `review = !sh /path/to/script` (arguments will get passed on automatically at this point).

I put the script up here: http://web.torek.net/torek/git/gerrit-review.sh.txt (the `.txt` extension is just so that browsers view it by default, rather than downloading it by default).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the git-review plugin? It should fit the bill quite happily!

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/git-review

Comment: I haven't and it looks interesting, but it's still an extra script rather than using git's extensive native features (we've already shifted from using our home-grown "topic branch" tagging in favor of git's "tracking" feature). It's frustrating because it looks like almost everything's there, except this last link in the chain.

Comment: I see what you mean, but consider that git once had almost no native features around version control. It is, at its heart, a content addressable filesystem. Everything else grew around it as little add-on scripts which eventually were ported into C for speed. git-review is as "native" as anything else, in a sense...