# How to set up a repo so that when cloned it has two different adresses for pushing and fetching?

Tags: git, url, git-clone

I have a git repository living at git://server.local/repo.git

Cloning with `git clone git://server.local/repot.git` sets up `origin` like this:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git://server.local/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git://server.local/repo.git (push)
```

But I would like this instead:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git://server.local/repo.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://server.local/realrepopath/repo.git (push)
```

I want this to be done automatically when cloning (without changing manually the remote URL).

Is that possible ?

Edit:
I don't want to have to run any command or script after the cloning is done. I would like to configure the remotes URL on the server so that I don't have to manually change them after cloning a repository.

Comment: Assuming there is a manual solution, then an automated solution is trivially achieved via a script...

Comment: Could you setup two separate remotes and push to one and pull from the other?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I don't want myself or any of my users to have to run any script or command after cloning. Remotes should ideally be set with git for pull/fetch and ssh for push as soon as cloning is done. If it is possible it can only be a server side setting.

Comment: @T0xicCode: I could technically do that but that would require more maintenance and attention to details.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the gerrit solution is still the accepted one.  Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101145/how-to-configure-specific-upstream-push-refspec-for-git-when-used-with-gerrit) to see how it can be done with a simple script.

Answer (score 0):

Once the repository is cloned you can execute

```
git remote set-url origin git://server.local/repo.git
git remote set-url --push origin ssh://server.local/realrepopath/repo.git
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to run scripts or hooks on a new `git clone` (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
git config --global url."ssh://server.local/realrepopath/".pushInsteadOf git://server.local/
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I tried server side, on the git repository but the setting doesn't apply when cloning on the client side.

Comment: @JohnChristopher, it should not work on server. But you need to run this command only once and this setting will be stored in your config `~/.gitconfig` and work for any repository from server.local. If you change `--global` to `--system` (if you have enough privileges) and this will work for anyone on the client computer.