# Equivalent of branch.<name>.merge for git-push

Tags: git, git-push, git-config

According to the `git-config` [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for `branch.<name>.merge`:

> **`branch.<name>.merge`**
>
> Defines, together with `branch.<name>.remote`, the
>   upstream branch for the given branch. It tells *git fetch*/*git pull*/*git
>   rebase* which branch to merge and can also affect *git push* (see
>   `push.default`).

Is there an equivalent setting to specify the upstream branch to push to, for the given branch? This is the behaviour I want to achieve - say I have a branch `A` with `remote` set to `origin`. On running `git push` from branch `A`, the result should be equivalent to running `git push refs/heads/A:refs/for/master`.

Alternatively, is there a value of `remote.*.push` which will achieve this behaviour? Setting `remote.origin.push` to `refs/heads/*:refs/for/master` resulted in an invalid refspec.

Comment: "say I have a branch A with remote set to origin"

I am unfamiliar with any ability for a branch to have a remote repo.  I am interpreting from this that your repository has an remote defined for a branch on your upstream repo called "origin".

On the other hand, I think what you are saying is that you have cloned an upstream repo, and your only remote defined locally is called "origin" and points to upstream master.

Comment: @ThatsAMorais I am not sure why that statement is ambiguous. But perhaps this will phrase it better. I have a `remote` named `origin` defined. My local repository has a branch named `A`. Also, `git config branch.A.remote` outputs `origin`.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  That is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this post may be helpful: [git alias for HEAD:refs/for/master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423893/git-alias-for-headrefs-for-master)

Comment: No, that isn't what I am asking. BTW, the answer you linked to is what you will find if you dig into the doc quote from my question "can also affect git push (see push.default)". When `push.default` is set to `upstream`, `branch.<name>.merge` is the remote branch that `git-push` uses with no refspec specified.

Comment: Okay, maybe more clarification is required.  I did not restate your question well, but I believe you are trying to avoid having to specify the ref to master each time (e.g. refs/heads/A:refs/for/master)

The solution I posted should set the upstream branch name permanently.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the refspec I want to push to is `refs/for/master` while the refspec that will get picked based on the upstream branch set to `master` is `refs/heads/master`. There isn't a branch name corresponding to this refspec AFAIK. BTW, as you might already have recognized, `refs/for/master` because gerrit is involved.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work either - that was my first attempt but with that refspec for `remote.origin.push`, `git push` in branch `A` ends up being equivalent to `git push origin refs/heads/A:refs/for/A`. That's how the `remote.*.push` value of `refs/heads/*:refs/for/*` gets interpreted.